# How to resolve "x is not a property of interface"

Tags: typescript, service, interface, angular8

I have tried a few different things to resolve this issue with no luck. I have created the interface below

```
export interface Force {
  store: number[];
  items: {
    itemName: string[];
    quantity: number[];
  }
}
```

and I call this function in my service

```
  data: Force[] = [
    {store: [],
    items:{
      itemName: [],
      quantity: []
    }}
  ]

constructor() { }

pushData(item){
  console.log(this.data);

this.data.store.push(item)

  }
}
```

But it says that store is not a property of Force[]. I think I am just not fully understanding how the interface works along with how to properly implement it. When I remove the [] from force (Force[] -> Force) it removes the error from store but gives me a handful of other errors. Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Please consider modifying the above code so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/GmZqPN) which demonstrates your issue (and does not introduce unrelated issues).  It helps others get working on a solution instead of having to spend time and effort working on seeing the problem.

Comment: Clearly `data: Force[]` is an Array. `store` is a property of your interface, not of the Array.